# MySQL database connection works on Live Server, but not on Test Server

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have a peculiar situation where the database connection works on the live server but not on my local computer.

I have the following connection script to access the database on both my local computer (running WAMP) as well as the live server:

```
function GetGlobalConnectionOptions()
{
    return array(
      'server' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '3306',
      'username' => 'sample_username',
      'password' => 'sample_password',
      'database' => 'sample_database'
);
```

I can connect to the live server database just fine. However, I'm not able to connect to the localhost database on my test computer. Here is the error I receive:

```
Could not connect to localhost: 
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'sample_database'
```

I don't understand how it won't work on my localhost. Also, I'm concerned that it is saying the user is ''@'localhost' instead of sample_username@localhost. Possibly that is part of the issue, but I'm stuck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

FYI I have both usernames set up in each database with all privileges granted.

Comment: I would trace your code back to the DB connection and make sure the username is being passed in correctly.

Comment: It seems to return the connection details, but the actual connection will be made with a function like `mysql_connect()`, `mysqli_connect()`, `new PDO()`, etc.

Comment: Also, you might want to run `show grants;` on your live server, as MySQL doesn't seem to be set up right if it's allowing connections without a username.

Answer (score 1):

In standard installations the users on localhost have to have explicit grants. So it does not suffice that user@% has access, it has to be `user@localhost`. As admin, enter `grant all privileges on * to user@localhost identified by 'password'; flush privileges;`